# Java Is it possible to send a httpServletRequest to a function?

Tags: java, function, timer

i got a function that looks like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/execute/{scriptId}")
public String execute(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @PathParam("scriptId") Long scriptId) {

/* ...  */
        engine.eval(getSrc(req.getServletContext().getRealPath("js/boot.js")));

        if (scriptId == 1L)
                engine.eval(getSrc(req.getServletContext().getRealPath("js/test.js")));
        else
                engine.eval(getSrc(req.getServletContext().getRealPath("js/test2.js")));

/* that above, its the only place i need the req  */

}
```

i call it from a html page...

```
<a href="rest/dss/execute/1">execute 1</a>
```

and it works fine...

now...i made a timer....and in the timer i need to call that function, but i have no idea how to get the httpservletrequest parameter for the function...

here is the code:

```
@Timeout
public void execute(Timer timer) {
    Long scriptId = Long.parseLong(timer.getInfo().toString());
    execute(/*here i need something*/, scriptId);

    System.out.println("Timer Service : " + scriptId);
    System.out.println("Current Time : " + new Date());
    System.out.println("Next Timeout : " + timer.getNextTimeout());
    System.out.println("Time Remaining : " + timer.getTimeRemaining());
    System.out.println("____________________________________________");

}
```

so, basically, i need to call that function with the timer...

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If your function doesn't need the `HttpServletRequest` (i.e. it doesn't need to call methods on the `HttpServletRequest`) then you can extract your existing code into an implementation method that does not depend on an `HttpServletRequest` and in your `execute` method call that implementation:

```
@GET
@Path("/execute/{scriptId}")
public String execute(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @PathParam("scriptId") Long scriptId) {
    return executeImpl(scriptId);
}

public String executeImpl(Long scriptId) {
    ...// your current implementation
}
```

And then your timer can also call that method:

```
@Timeout
public void execute(Timer timer) {
    Long scriptId = Long.parseLong(timer.getInfo().toString());
    executeImpl(scriptId);

    System.out.println("Timer Service : " + scriptId);
    System.out.println("Current Time : " + new Date());
    System.out.println("Next Timeout : " + timer.getNextTimeout());
    System.out.println("Time Remaining : " + timer.getTimeRemaining());
    System.out.println("____________________________________________");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's just an interface which you can implement.

Of course implementing it to do something useful may not be trivial, depending on what you're doing with the request in the other method.

Getting a ready implementation of an HttpServletRequest from some 3rd party library that implements the JEE standard might help, but may well be overkill.

Comment: how to do it ? just download the library and implement? and what then? i still dont know how to call the function

Comment: so in the end, even if i implement some other interface, i still dont know how to do it

Comment: It's not a good idea to implement the `HttpServletRequest` for something as simple as this. I like @Thomas's suggestion better.

Comment: @BheshGurung if it's not needed, yes. But from the original question there's no way to determine that.